# What is the best way to have a list with a lot of elements in it (in python)?

Tags: python, list

I have a few lists with around 200 numbers in each of them, and they take up a lot of vertical space in my code so I want to ask if there's a better way to do it? Like can I hide the elements in my code so it just says something like
list=np.array[...]

Comment: Can you show your current code?

Comment: You can put your lists in a separate module (`.py` file) and import them from your main module.

Comment: I'm not able to answer your question, but as a suggestion for why your question is receiving downvotes: 1. It's very open-ended. Questions like "What's the best way ..." are hard to answer because there are usually many good ways and not one "best" way. 2. It's not clear (to me at least) what you're asking. What code are you trying to write? And 3. You haven't shown any attempt to solve the problem yourself, like writing your own code or pseudocode.

Answer (score 2):

The usual strategies are:

1. Use an editor that supports some kind of *folding*. Even ancient tools like vim allow collapsing lists. I'm moderately partial to this solution and am generally a fan of tools giving multiple views into the same source code depending on what you're currently trying to do with it.
2. Put the lists somewhere else. A comment suggested another module like a .py file, but you could also use a data file and do something like `with open('mydata.txt') as f: L = list(map(int, f))`, take advantage of the gzip or lzma models, use a binary format, or all kinds of things.
3. If you're only talking about a few hundred elements, a strategy I've seen in low-level C code with lookup tables is to take advantage of both the horizontal and the vertical space. Something like the following:

```
L = [
    1234, 5678, 1345, 2345, # as wide as you need, end with a comma
    3857, 1938, 1984, 1293,
    # and as deep as you need
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using something like JSON to store the data if you want to use pure python. The `json` library provided with python provides easy ways to load the data.

`<file_name>.json`:

```
{
    'a': [
        1,
        2,
        3
    ],
    'b': [
        4,
        5,
        6
    ]
}
```

```py
import json
data = json.load(<file_name>) # Retrieves your lists
data[<list_name>] # Gets a list given the name of the list
data['a'] # Output: [1,2,3]
data['b'] # Output: [4,5,6]
```

If you're comfortable with NumPy, you can also use `numpy.savez`

```py
import numpy as np

# Let's assume you have a dictionary of number lists in the variable "data"

data = {'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6]}

# Saving data
np.savez("<filename>.npz", **data)

# Loading data
data = np.load("<filename>.npz")

# Retrieving lists
data['a'] # Output: np.array([1,2,3])
data['b'] # Output: np.array([4,5,6])
```